# Filter Columns from Pandas Dataframe with given list when list elements may or may not be present as column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe and I need to filter out the columns from the dataframe if the columns are present in a given list.

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]], columns=list('ABCDE'))
```

This is the dataframe.

```
   A  B  C  D   E
0  1  2  3  4   5
1  6  7  8  9  10
```

I have a list.

```
fil_lst = ['A', 'D', 'F']
```

The list may contain column names that are not present in the dataframe. I need only the columns that are present in the dataframe.

I need the resulting dataframe like,

```
   A  D
0  1  4
1  6  9
```

I know it can be done with the help of list comprehension like,

```
new_df = df[[col for col in fil_lst if col in df.columns]]
```

But as I have a huge dataframe, it is better if I don't use this computationally expensive process.
Is it possible to vectorize this in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for test membership in columns and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by columns, so `:` mean select all rows and columns by mask:

```
fil_lst = ['A', 'D', 'F']
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(fil_lst)]
print(df)
   A  D
0  1  4
1  6  9
```

Or use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
fil_lst = ['A', 'D', 'F']
df = df[df.columns.intersection(fil_lst)]
print(df)
   A  D
0  1  4
1  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with large lists, and the focus is on performance more than order of columns, you can use [`set intersection`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp):

```
In [2944]: fil_lst = ['A', 'D', 'F']
In [2945]: col_list = df.columns.tolist()

In [2947]: df = df[list(set(col_list) & set(fil_lst))]

In [2947]: df
Out[2947]: 
   D  A
0  4  1
1  9  6
```

**EDIT:** If order of columns is important, then do this:

```
In [2953]: df = df[sorted(set(col_list) & set(fil_lst), key = col_list.index)]

In [2953]: df
Out[2953]: 
   A  D
0  1  4
1  6  9
```

Comment: It change order of columns, it should be problem.

Comment: Since OP wants a subset of df in a performant way, I don't think the order of columns matter so much. Let OP come back on this.

Comment: Yop, we can see if order is important or not. Most time yes, here maybe not.

Comment: Yes. The order of the columns is important in my case.

Comment: @AsifIqbal Have added another part to my answer for maintaining order.